# SVG display difference between <img> and <object>

Tags: image, object, caching, svg

What's the difference between displaying a SVG image in an `<img>` or `<object>` tag? I was facing some problems using SVG images in a `<img>` tag on Android 3.1:

[image]

The shape in the upper example is an `<img>` tag and the lowest example is the exact same image but display in an `<object>`. 
Why is this displayed a different way? And is an `<object>` cached like an `<img>`?

What do you guys suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Differences when SVG is [used as an image](http://www.w3.org/TR/svg-integration/#secure-animated-mode) (html `<img>` SVG `<image>` or CSS background images)

- no scripting
- no interactivity
- no external dependencies (complete in a single file)
- no DOM (i.e. no script access into them from outside)
- can be copied into canvas via drawImage

I suspect you're suffering from the no external dependencies rule. You may also want to check that the SVG data has a preserveAspectRatio attribute on the root element and if it does that the value of that attribute is not none.