# How to better fit svg into an html document - in the img tag or in the svg tag?

Tags: html, svg

What is the difference between entering svg images with the `img` tag and `svg` tag?

I know that it is possible to implement animation in `svg` tag, but are there any other differences?

Comment: are you manually adding them? because if you are retrieving them from a database for example is easier using SVG tag

Comment: I just have an image downloaded from avocode svg inside with the code that I ran through the optimizer

Comment: Is there a difference, for example, in display performance or download speed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538325/svg-display-difference-between-img-and-object

Comment: The article didn't help me much

Comment: I' m running a test so far, I' m about to give the answer to my question