# SVG currentColor do not inherit from parent division when created from CSS

Tags: css, svg

I try to integrate a SVG from a CSS file with the following code:

```css
.circle:before {
    content: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8, <svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill="currentColor" d="M256 8C119 8 8 119 8 256s111 248 248 248 248-111 248-248S393 8 256 8z"/></svg>');
}
```

```html
<div style="color:red; fill:blue;">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill="currentColor" d="M256 8C119 8 8 119 8 256s111 248 248 248 248-111 248-248S393 8 256 8z"/></svg>
</div>
```

I can't figure out why the color is applied when the SVG is inserted in the HTML and is not applied when the SVG is created from the CSS?

Comment: when used inside CSS it's like using iframe. It cannot interact with anything from the outside

Comment: You can set color from outside Font awesome icons. How they do?

Comment: font Awesome aren't embeded that way using url. They are either used as font or the SVG is added to the code

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48608619/8620333

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538325/svg-display-difference-between-img-and-object/30538817#30538817 - specifically no external dependencies for SVG used as an image and CSS content counts as an image.

Comment: OK. I see, what is the best alternative? I still do not understand how Font Awesome works.

Comment: FontAwesome turns the SVGs into a font. So it's just like displaying any other text.